# How to change input pin of FreqCounter Arduino Uno/Dumilanove library?

Tags: lcd, frequency

The following link to the library defines arduino pin 5 for input pin for signal.
 
 https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_FreqCount.html

But the problem is I'm using an 16x2 LCD display with the arduino pin 5. The display needs pin 5 to work. So the question can solved in two ways,to both of which I don't know the answer.
1. Change LCD pin number to other pin. (Tried it was a failure. I've probably done it wrong)
2. Change the input pin for the freqcount library.

Any idea how to get past this bottleneck?

Comment: how did you try to change the LCD pin to other pin? can you show a minimum of code to demonstrate?

Comment: I've used this to try changing pins. `LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 4,3 , 2, 1);` in place of `LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5,4 , 3, 2);` This fails for some reason. Nothing appears on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library makes use of the hardware peripheral Timer 1 which has its input on pin 5 of the Uno.

It can't be changed.  You have no choice in that.

You will have to move the LCD to another pin instead.

Comment: any idea how to do that?

Comment: Like you tried before, but don't use pins 0 or 1 - they are shared with Serial and sometimes that gets in the way - especially if you're also using Serial for communication with a PC at the same time.